# How to ignore a value when (for loop) through object?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, javascript-objects

I'm looping through an object using `for loop`, and I would like to ignore some specific values when looping.

This block of code is responsible to loop through my object:

```
let acceptAll = function (rawContent){
   for(let i in rawContent)
   if(!rawContent[i]) return false;
   return true
};
```

I have a value in `rawContent` that I would like to ignore when looping through, is that possible?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't said what `rawContent` is, but if it's an array, `for-in` isn't usually the right choice for looping through it. I do a rundown of your options in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript/9329476#9329476), but for most use cases you'd use `for-of` in modern environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of options:

1. `if` `continue`
2. `if` on its own

Here's `if` `continue`:

```
for (let i in rawContent) {
    if (/*...you want to ignore it...*/) {
        continue; // Skips the rest of the loop body
    }
    // ...do something with it
}
```

Or `if` on its own:

```
for (let i in rawContent) {
    if (/*...you DON'T want to ignore it...*/) {
        // ...do something with it
    }
}
```

---

Side note: That's a `for-in` loop, not a `for` loop (even though it starts with `for`). JavaScript has three separate looping constructs that start with `for`:

- Traditional `for` loop:

  ```
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        // ...
  }
  ```
- `for-in` loop:

  ```
  for (let propertyName in someObject) {
        // ...
  }
  ```

  *(If you never change the value in `propertyName` in the loop body, you can use `const` instead of `let`.)*
- `for-of` loop:

  ```
  for (let element of someIterableLikeAnArray) {
        // ...
  }
  ```

  *(If you never change the value in `element` in the loop body, you can use `const` instead of `let`.)*

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are searching for the continue keyword:

```js
let array = [1,2,3,4]

for(let i of array){
    if(i === 2) continue
  console.log(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain an array of values which you would like to ignore. For example

```js
const valuesToIgnore = [1,5,15,20]
let acceptSome = (rawContent) => {
    for (let i of rawContent) {
        if (valuesToIgnore.includes(i)) {
        // These are the values you want to ignore
            console.log('Ignoring', i)
        } else {
        // These are the values you do not want to ignore
            console.log('Not Ignoring', i)
        }
    }
}

// And you invoke your function like this -

acceptSome([1,2,3,5,10,15,20,25])
```